# Gitlab CI Rules - Run only on push to origin/master

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm looking for a bit of an unusual use case, where I only run certain jobs after a push to origin/master. In practice, this only happens when a merge goes in so my first attempt at this was the following rule:

`if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'`

This didn't work though, presumably because the actual merge commit pushed to origin/master is not considered a `merge_request_event`.

Any way to achieve this?

Note: I don't simply use `if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'` to avoid running on a push to a non-origin fork's `master` branch.

Comment: may be you may check CI_PROJECT_PATH is your origin ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do this using the uniquely assigned `PROJECT_ID` gitlab variable (it's different for each fork).  So the following works:

`if: '$CI_PROJECT_ID == "<origin fork's project_id>" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'`

The project ID can be found in Settings on gitlab.